# “Invalid syntax” error after for statement

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I try to get a list of URL's from a website. I have located the right bit of code and named that variable 'table'. When I enter the code "for links in table.findall('tr', href=True)", it returns:

File "", line 1
for links in table.findall('tr', href=True)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I have tried to replace the 'tr' for 'a', but that gives me the same result. Right before this line of code I gave the command print(table), which gave me the right bit of html code, so I assume that everything upto declaring the table variable should be ok.

For clarity here is my full code. Again, I'm sorry if it is hard to read or sloppy looking. Tips & tricks are always appreciated.

code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib
import urllib.request

URL = 'https://www.transfermarkt.nl/eredivisie/kreuztabelle/wettbewerb/NL1/saison_id/2013'
Page = requests.get(URL, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36 Edg/84.0.522.48'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(Page.text, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('div', {"class":"responsive-table"})
for links in table.findall('tr', href=True)
```

Comment: You need to place a colon (`:`) at the end of the for loop condition, i.e. `for links in table.findall('tr', href=True):` ;)

Comment: What should this code do? The `for` is incomplete, it misses a colon `:` and the suite (body). Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: There are multiple links to other sites (href) in this part of html code. I'm hoping to extract a list of all this links. I added the colon and I added the command print(links) as SetMao suggested but now I get that the object is not callable

Comment: When I insert an underscore `_` between find and all (so: find_all), it works, but it only gives me back only 1 record. I expected more. What's there more to fix :-)?

Answer (score 0):

Try replace

```
for links in table.findall('tr', href=True)
```

to

```
for links in table.findall('tr', href=True):
    print(links)
```

You can get more information in python official tutorial.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: Hi SetMao, now it says: 'NoneType object is not callable'

Comment: Print your table, it looks like your table is None.